# makefile with categories

Tags: makefile

Imagine I have files that are categorized in my mind but cannot be distinguished by any kind of naming scheme, and they reside in the same directory:

```
apple cherry celery onion
```

I have two rules, one recipe for pie and one for soup.

If I implement these recipes as implicit rules:

```
fruits:= apple cherry
vegetables:= celery onion

%.soup : %
        @echo "making soup"
        cp $< $@

%.pie : %
        @echo "making pie"
        cp $< $@
```

Then I allow terrible meals to be constructed:

```
> touch celery
> make celery.pie
making pie 
cp celery celery.pie #bleech this should not be allowed
```

But if I use explicit rules:

```
fruits:= apple cherry
vegetables:= celery onion

pies:=$(addsuffix .pie,$(fruits))
soups:=$(addsuffix .soup,$(vegetables))

$(pies) : $(fruits)
        @echo "making pie"
        cp $< $@


$(soups) : $(vegetables)
        @echo "making soup"
        cp $< $@
```

I am forced to establish dependencies that don't exist in reality:

```
> touch apple
> make apple.pie
make: *** No rule to make target `cherry', needed by `apple.pie'.  Stop.
```

How can I tell Make about file categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [static pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
fruits:= apple cherry
vegetables:= celery onion

$(vegetables:%=%.soup) : %.soup : %
        @echo "making soup"
        cp $< $@

$(fruits:%=%.pie) : %.pie : %
        @echo "making pie"
        cp $< $@
```